# Can I further speed up query to find all objects within a range in python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, data-structures

Lets say I have a list of a simple dataclass like:

```
@dataclass
class Widget:
    category: str
    weight: int
```

I want to write a function that returns all widgets that equal a certain category and are within a certain weight like:

```
def query_widgets(category, lo_weight, hi_weight):
    pass
```

Assuming this list is fixed and I can preprocess this however I like, what is the fastest way to do this purely in python?

My solution is to sort the list by weight, create a map of category to widgets, and then find the indexes of the first and last occurrence by weight. This lets me quickly find the start and stop index.

Is there anyway to speed this up? I tried using bisect instead of loop to find the indexes but that performed slightly worse.

Full Example:

```
import random
import time
from collections import defaultdict
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Iterable


@dataclass
class Widget:
    categories: str
    weight: int


class WidgetSearch:

    def __init__(self, widgets: Iterable[Widget]) -> None:
        self.widgets = sorted(widgets, key=lambda w: w.weight)
        self.category_to_widgets = defaultdict(list)
        self.category_weight_start_idx = defaultdict(dict)
        self.category_weight_end_idx = defaultdict(dict)
        for m in self.widgets:
            for category in m.categories:
                self.category_to_widgets[category].append(m)
        for category, widgets in self.category_to_widgets.items():
            prev_weight = None
            for i, widget in enumerate(widgets):
                weight = widget.weight
                if prev_weight != weight:
                    self.category_weight_start_idx[category][weight] = i
                    if prev_weight is not None:
                        self.category_weight_end_idx[category][prev_weight] = i
                prev_weight = weight
            self.category_weight_end_idx[category][prev_weight] = len(widgets)

    def _find_most_recent_start_idx(self, category: str, weight: int) -> int:
        if weight in self.category_weight_start_idx[category]:
            return self.category_weight_start_idx[category][weight]

        for idx_weight, idx in self.category_weight_start_idx[category].items():
            if idx_weight > weight:
                return idx

        return 0

    def _find_most_recent_end_idx(self, category: str, weight: int) -> int:
        if weight in self.category_weight_end_idx[category]:
            return self.category_weight_end_idx[category][weight]

        for idx_weight in reversed(self.category_weight_end_idx[category].keys()):
            if idx_weight < weight:
                return self.category_weight_end_idx[category][idx_weight]
        return None

    def query_widgets(self, category: str, lo_weight: int, hi_weight: int) -> Iterable[Widget]:
        if category not in self.category_to_widgets or lo_weight > hi_weight:
            return []
        start = self._find_most_recent_start_idx(category, lo_weight)
        end = self._find_most_recent_end_idx(category, hi_weight)
        return self.category_to_widgets[category][start:end]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    widgets = []
    categories = list('ABCDEF')
    for _ in range(10000):
        cats = random.sample(categories, random.randint(1, 3))
        widgets.append(Widget(categories=cats, weight=random.randint(1000, 2000)))
    ws = WidgetSearch(widgets)
    start = time.perf_counter_ns()
    widgets = ws.query_widgets('C', 1400, 1800)
    end = time.perf_counter_ns()
    dur = (end - start) / 1000.0
    print(f'# Found: {len(widgets)} in {dur} microsec')
```

Comment: Can you add driver code that runs a test case? Also, I don't understand `m.categories`, since `m` is a Widget...

Comment: This will be very strongly dependent on data, which queries you made before, etc.

Comment: @trincot updated the example to run. Widget is just an arbitrary name.

Comment: @btilly re: "queries you made before" you mean caching previous queries? Assume just making the first query as fast possible.

Comment: OK, I see you fixed the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get slightly better results on my machine with using `operator.attrgetter` + `bisect` (but as stated in the comments, your results may vary, it's strongly dependent on your data):

```py
from operator import attrgetter
from bisect import bisect, bisect_left


def create_index(widgets):
    index = {}

    for w in widgets:
        for cat in w.categories:
            index.setdefault(cat, []).append(w)

    for k in index:
        index[k] = sorted(index[k], key=lambda w: w.weight)

    return index


def query_widgets(index, category, lo_weight, hi_weight, key=attrgetter("weight")):
    widgets = index.get(category)

    if not widgets:
        return []

    idx_lo = bisect_left(widgets, lo_weight, key=key)
    idx_hi = bisect(widgets, hi_weight, lo=idx_lo, key=key)

    return widgets[idx_lo:idx_hi]


index = create_index(widgets)

w1 = query_widgets(index, "C", 1400, 1800)
w2 = ws.query_widgets("C", 1400, 1800)      # ws is your `WidgetSearch` class

assert len(w1) == len(w2)
```

Comment: It comes out to about the same in my use case but the code is a lot simpler just using bisect without the extra complication of storing separate pointers to indices. Thanks!

Comment: This is very elegant! I wonder if using numpy array as an input to bisect would result in better performance. Intuition tells me that for large sizes of indices array it should have some impact